# Determine if date field is NaN or empty

Tags: javascript, date, acrobat

I offer the following code forreview:

```
//THIS VALIDATES THE DATE ENTERED
var cMsg = "The date you entered is invalid.\n\nPlease enter a date that does not pre-date the previous entry date.";
var nIcon = 0;
var nType = 0;
var cTitle = "DATE ERROR";
var str = event.target.name;
var res = str.charAt(str.length-1);
var d1 = Date.parse(this.getField("0." + (res-1)).value);
var d2 = Date.parse(event.value);
if(d1 != null) {
if (d1 > d2) {
    app.beep();
    app.alert(cMsg, nIcon, nType, cTitle);
event.value = "";
}
} else {
var cMsg = "This is an invalid entry\n\nThe previous date entry cannot be empty.\n\nPlease use the entry above first.";
    app.beep();
    app.alert(cMsg, nIcon, nType, cTitle);
}
```

THE RULES:

- d2 can't (or shouldn't) be a date predating d1
- d2 can't (or shouldn't) be populated unless d1 is
    first populated

Perhaps instead of disallowing input (a strict enforcement), we just alert the user and confirm they desire to continue even if the intended rule is violated...that may be better.

This has proved difficult for me. Please assist if can.

Comment: Refactoring requests are offtopic here. Look at [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `d1 != null` will always be true as *d1* will never be null, it will always be a number or NaN, both of which are always `!= null`.

Comment: adiga: I am so lost...can you provide me a fix PLEASE?